# Heroku delayed_job error - Deserialize error?

Tags: heroku, rake, delayed-job

Can someone help me understand this error? Can't figure out how to take a ride of this and it's stopping all of my delayed_job...

```
heroku rake jobs:work --app thehockeycommunity --trace
** Execute jobs:work
[Worker(host:8e8e4caf-9879-4fd7-94c5-d22d866c5720 pid:4)] New Relic Ruby Agent Monitoring DJ worker host:8e8e4caf-9879-4fd7-94c5-d22d866c5720 pid:4
[Worker(host:8e8e4caf-9879-4fd7-94c5-d22d866c5720 pid:4)] Starting job worker
rake aborted!
syntax error on line 2874, col 3: `'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.0.7/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:103:in `deserialize'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.0.7/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:69:in `payload_object'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.0.7/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:55:in `name'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.0.7/lib/delayed/worker.rb:165:in `handle_failed_job'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.0.7/lib/delayed/worker.rb:128:in `run'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.0.7/lib/delayed/worker.rb:173:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.0.7/lib/delayed/worker.rb:106:in `work_off'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.0.7/lib/delayed/worker.rb:105:in `times'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.0.7/lib/delayed/worker.rb:105:in `work_off'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.0.7/lib/delayed/worker.rb:80:in `start'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.0.7/lib/delayed/worker.rb:79:in `start'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.0.7/lib/delayed/worker.rb:76:in `loop'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.0.7/lib/delayed/worker.rb:76:in `start'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.0.7/lib/delayed/tasks.rb:13
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `run'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/bin/rake:19
Tasks: TOP => jobs:work
new-host-4:The-Hockey-Community alextoul$
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old, unanswered question, but if anyone else stumbles on this it might help to note that empty YAML files in your project can sometimes trigger errors like this.